# Nested "if" condition in Pandas: compare value in one column to values int dict in other column

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have DataFrame like this:

```
Index Name Age NestedDict      
1     Adam  45 {"Dataobject":[{"Adam":26, "id":69},{"Adam":45, "id":63},{"Adam":40, "id":20}]
2     etc
```

I want to:
for each record in DF compare value in Age column with every "Adam" value in dict in NestedDict column and if there's a match then assing it's "id" value to new column and ideally drop other "Adams" from the dict.

I know I can access the dict with "apply":

```
DF.NestedDict.apply(lambda x: x.get("Dataobject")
```

And I tried to get the "Adam" values from the dict like this:

```
DF.NestedDict.apply(lambda x: [i.get("Adam") for i in x.get("Dataobject")])
```

which gives me

```
[26, 45, 40]
```

but then, I don't know how to make if condition to compare every value from list to DF.Age and if there's match then how to get the 'id' from the dict.

Comment: Is there always a matching record for that age value in a row?

Comment: Each record has Age value in column, but there might be no matching/corresponding  value in the dictionary (if there's no match, it would be great to assign "no match" value to DF

Answer (score 0):

Use nested list comprehension with `zip`, also return first match value by `next` with default string `no match` if not exist:

```
df['new_id'] = [next(iter([i.get("id") for i in x.get("Dataobject") 
                if i.get("Adam") == y]), 'no match')
                for y, x in zip(df['Age'], df['NestedDict'])]
```

**Sample**:

```
d = {"Dataobject":[{"Adam":26, "id":69},{"Adam":45, "id":63},{"Adam":40, "id":20}]}
df = pd.DataFrame({'Age':[45, 40, 38], 'NestedDict':[d, d, d]})

df['new_id'] = [next(iter([i.get("id") for i in x.get("Dataobject") 
                if i.get("Adam") == y]), 'no match')
                for y, x in zip(df['Age'], df['NestedDict'])]

print (df)


   Age                                         NestedDict    new_id
0   45  {'Dataobject': [{'Adam': 26, 'id': 69}, {'Adam...        63
1   40  {'Dataobject': [{'Adam': 26, 'id': 69}, {'Adam...        20
2   38  {'Dataobject': [{'Adam': 26, 'id': 69}, {'Adam...  no match
```